# XPAges: "java.io.NotSerializableException: lotus.domino.local.Document"

Tags: jsf, serialization, xpages, viewstate

I have an XPage which holds one Notes document. The intention of this page is just to *show* some relevant fields of the document.

Accessing the page first time is ok. And also when showing later again *without* changing the underlaying document is ok.

But when I navigate from this to another XPage, and change the document there (yes, I have another page dedicated to *edit* the document), and then come back to the "show" page, I get the `java.io.NotSerializableException` in the render Response Phase.

Strange: it is for a `lotus.domino.local.Document` ... I never want to save/serialize a document ... :-o

**What I've done to find the bug in my code:**

1. I logged the **viewScope** content in beforeRenderResponse Event of the page, but there are only simple objects (strings and booleans).
2. I set the viewState of the page to "`nostate`".
3. I set the **readonly** attribute of the page to "`true`".
4. I removed every "*on page loading*" data-bindings (switched '`${...}`' to '`#{...}`')

So what else can I do to find the point of code, where some kind of document want to be saved?
What are typical error causes in this case?

Thanks for any help to help myself! :-)

My Stacktrace:

```
23.11.16 10:30: Exception Thrown
Context Path: /.../.../myApp.nsf
Page Name: /page_ShowData.xsp
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.io.NotSerializableException: lotus.domino.local.Document
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractStateManager.saveSerializedView(AbstractStateManager.java:121)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.StateManagerImpl.saveSerializedView(StateManagerImpl.java:152)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._saveViewState(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:455)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.saveViewState(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:449)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:324)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:588)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:865)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:808)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:577)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: lotus.domino.local.Document
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:728)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor652.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1059)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1502)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:942)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor637.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1059)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1502)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:438)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:417)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:417)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:417)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:417)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager.saveSerializedView(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:294)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager.doSaveSerializedView(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:269)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.FileStateManager.doSaveSerializedView(FileStateManager.java:290)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.FileStateManager.doSaveSerializedView(FileStateManager.java:270)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractStateManager.saveSerializedView(AbstractStateManager.java:114)
    ... 25 more
```

My page_ShowData.xsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" pageTitle="Show Data"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" readonly="true"
    viewState="nostate"
    afterPageLoad="#{javascript:print('page_ShowData.afterPageLoad()');}">
    <!-- ... -->
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="stamm" formName="Masterdata" ignoreRequestParams="false">
            <xp:this.action>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    // ensure to set the unid if known
                    if (viewScope.stammid == null){
                        viewScope.stammid = param.get('documentId');
                    }

                    if(typeof viewScope.stammid == "undefined" || viewScope.stammid == null || viewScope.stammid == ""){
                        return; // empty means 'create'
                    } else {
                        return 'openDocument';
                    }
                }]]>
            </xp:this.action>
            <xp:this.documentId>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:return viewScope.stammid;}]]>
            </xp:this.documentId>


            <xp:this.postOpenDocument>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    <!-- set some viewScope vars -->
                }]]>
            </xp:this.postOpenDocument>

            <xp:this.postNewDocument>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    <!-- set some viewScope vars -->
                }]]>
            </xp:this.postNewDocument>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
   </xp:this.data>

   <!-- ... -->

   <xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
     <![CDATA[#{javascript:
        try{
            // print all viewScope vars
            var vsKeys:java.util.Set = viewScope.keySet();
            for (var k in vsKeys){
                var v = viewScope.get(k);
                print('viewScope - ['+k.toString()+'] (serializable='+(k instanceof java.io.Serializable)+') = ['+v+'] (instance='+(typeof v)+', serializable='+(v instanceof java.io.Serializable)+')');
            }
     }]]>

    </xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>



    <!-- some UI content -->

</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On one of those two XPages you're storing a NotesDocument (not DominoDocument datasource, but a NotesDocument object) in a scoped variable. Domino objects aren't serializable, which is what's throwing the error. The most likely place is the page you're moving *from*.

If you need access to a specific document, store the UNID of the document in the scoped variable and use `database.getDocumentByUNID()` to retrieve it. That's almost certainly what the DominoDocument datasource does.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment. I already knew that I can't store NotesDocument in a scoped variable. That's why I'm logging the viewScope vars as a first step to find the bug. But all vars are booleans or strings ... And actually I don't want to save or cache a document. The question is, how to find the code fragment that put a document into a scope ... But you gave a good hint: I only looked at my _target_ page (the readonly one), maybe I have to look at my _source_ page (the editable one). I'll write my results later here ...

Comment: Is it possible it may be some UIControl or DataSource that has a computed property that resolves to a NotesDocument? ie instead of a scope variable. 
Perhaps a clue is that the writeObjectEx is within it's 6th recursion, so think of something that is around 6 deep in the scopes / control tree. Are you 100% sure that the error is from the Show Page? If you are switching back FROM the edit page, wouldn't the edit page be the one that is being serialized?

Comment: So. You both are right: the error came from the _target_ page. There was a custom control made by a colleague. And he had a NotesDocument as (calculated) datasource. He found the error and reported it to me before I'm jumping out the window :-) Thanks for your help!!!!